# TypeError: require(...).connect is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, connection, rabbitmq, ionic2

```
node version: v4.4.4
npm version: 3.9.2
ionic version (app): 2.0.0-beta.7
amqplib version: 0.4.1
```

I am currently trying to develop an app using Ionic 2 framework and I have decided to introduce messaging in my app by using RabbitMQ within [this library](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node). Feel free to inspect the code [here](https://github.com/daixtrose/Ionic2AndVS2015/tree/MyIonic2App_antonio/MyIonic2App_2) for any further reference.

1. First of all, I installed the library manually using `npm install https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node.git` because the release version from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) is [outdated](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/issues/251).
2. After that, I added the Typescript definitions for the library via `typings install dt~amqplib --global --save`.
3. I created a new page for my app called *[Page2](https://github.com/daixtrose/Ionic2AndVS2015/blob/MyIonic2App_antonio/MyIonic2App_2/app/pages/page2/page2.ts)* where the library is imported...

   ```
   import * as amqp from 'amqplib/callback_api';
   [...]
   ```

   ... and used to connect to the server...

   ```
   [...]
   setConnection() {
       amqp.connect(this.connectionUrl, (err: any, connection: amqp.Connection) => {
           this.connection = connection;
           this.connection.createChannel((err: any, channel: amqp.Channel) => {
               this.channel = channel;
               this.channel.assertExchange(this.exchange, 'topic', { durable: false });
           });
       });
   }
   [...]
   ```
4. The problem comes when I try to run it (I have done it using both an **emulator** and a **native device** running Android). If I try to hit the *Set connection* button, I get the following error:

[image]

The error is linked to the line `sock = require('net').connect(sockopts, onConnect);` of *[connect.js](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/lib/connect.js)* file. Is there any trouble with NodeJS *[Net](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/net.html#net_net_connect_path_connectlistener)* module in the library or is it a misconfiguration I made somewhere in my app?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nodeJS server in an ionic app that your library can use.

Comment: Excuse me, could you explain what you mean a little bit better?